# CRM v9 - Saving data in CRM entity through C# code

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created a new CRM entity with 2 fields **Name** and **Value**.
In my C# code I am fetching the same two values with their names from Microsoft Unified Service Desk. Now I have these records in my C# Code and now i want to save these in the CRM Entity.
I am using below code to fetch the values for now,

```
 string QuestionAnswer = string.Empty;

        if (dialog.QuestionControlValidate)
        {
            if (ContextParameterName != string.Empty)
            {
                var ctx = Context.GetContext();

                if (dialog.QuestionControlType == "TextBox")
                    QuestionAnswer = dialog.QuestionControlTextQuestionAnswer.ToString();
                else if (dialog.QuestionControlType == "RadioButton")
                    QuestionAnswer = dialog.QuestionControlRadioButtonSelectionAnswer.ToString();

                var updatedContext = new Context(ctx)
                {
                    [ContextParameterName] = QuestionAnswer
                };

// Code to be added here
            }
```

I am getting the **Name** inside **ContextParameterName** and **Value** inside **QuestionAnswer**. I want to store the these records inside CRM Entity which has the name and value fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting the data from Microsoft USD inside C# code and then wanted to save it in CRM Entity. And since in USD the connection is created automatically with the CRM environment therefore I achieved it without explicitly defining the connection.

```
                dictionary.Add("name", new CrmDataTypeWrapper(ContextParameterName, CrmFieldType.Raw));
                dictionary.Add("value", new CrmDataTypeWrapper(QuestionAnswer, CrmFieldType.Raw));
                dictionary.Add("id", new CrmDataTypeWrapper(updatedContext["Id"], CrmFieldType.Raw));

                Guid EvntId = _client.CrmInterface.CreateNewRecord("historicaldata",dictionary,"",false,new System.Guid());
```

The **CreateNewRecord** method creates a new activity against the target entity type

Comment: Where is ICrmUtilityHostedControl ?

Comment: protected ICrmUtilityHostedControl _client;

Answer (score 0):

Your code to create a Record in CRM would be something like below

Entity customEntity = new Entity

```
 Entity abc = new Entity()
                {
                    LogicalName = "new_EntityName",
                    ["fieldName"] = ContextParameterName,
                    ["fieldValue"] = QuestionAnswer

                };
                Guid newEntityRecordGuid = CrmConn.Create(abc);
```

newEntityRecordGuid will have newly created Record Guid

Comment: I want to create the record using ICrmUtilityHostedControl

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global Manager hosted control and use CreateEntity action. Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/unified-service-desk/global-manager-hosted-control?view=dynamics-usd-4.1